# Repair after/before decommissioning in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, repair, cassandra-2.2

We're planning to decommission few nodes from our Apache Cassandra 2.2.8 cluster, do we need to do repair after decommission or before decommission? or no need of repair at all in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think no repair is needed if decommission, because decommission is a process that a node which is going to leave from a cluster transfers its own data to the other nodes.

Comment: yep make sense to me. Thanks for reply.